# Como dividir inteiros e obter valor com parte decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, operadores, tipagem, matemática

Estou tentando dividir os seguintes valores em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23):

```
Double media = 0.0;
int soma = 7;
int cont = 2;
media = soma / cont;
```

Está retornando `3`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isto tem a ver com tipagem. Você está dividindo 2 inteiros, então recebe um inteiro, se quer um resultado que não seja inteiro precisa dividir números que não sejam inteiros, pode fazer um *cast*, é seguro fazer em algo que aumenta a precisão:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int soma = 7;
        int cont = 2;
        double media = (double)soma / (double)cont;
        WriteLine(media);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TMe6YV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kqzzvx). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/DivideIntegerResultDouble.cs).

Não precisa converter os dois operandos, se um deles for `double`, o resultado já será `double` para garantir que não tenha perda de precisão.

Comment: continua a dar-me inteiro

Comment: Estou mostrando que não dá.

Comment: então preciso sempre de fazer cast usando (double) ?

Comment: Se é o que deseja, sim. Mas pode não querer isso, primeiro precisa saber o que deseja.

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes, um calculo com dois inteiros sempre irá retornar um valor tipo inteiro. Parece estranho no início, mas para o compilador não faz sentido mudar a tipagem, independente do calculo sendo feito. Computador não erra e faz exatamente o que lhe é ordenado. Outro problema é usar `double`para o calculo. `double` é um flutuande de base **binária**, enquanto `decimal` é um flutuante de base **decimal**, que é a qual usamos. Vc pode ter resultados inesperados se usar `double` sem realmente saber suas características.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi então devo usar decimal?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes depende do que você quer fazer, depende da exatidão que precisa, o `double` é adequado para muita situações.

Comment: Decimal é recomendado para dinheiro. Como colega @bigown disse, vai depender o que você vai fazer.

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes se for para guardar valores decimais, como monetários, dimensões, etc, sim, use Decimal

Comment: @bigown não precisa colocar `(double)soma / (double)cont;`, apenas deixa isso `(double)soma / cont;`, pois essa conversão já é redundante.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda eu coloquei ambos e escrevi que não precisa na resposta, aí a pessoa escolhe como deseja.

Answer (score 4):

Não faz sentido você usar o tipo `int` que sempre vai retornar número inteiro.

Você pode usar tipo `decimal` ou `double` dependendo o que vai fazer:

```
decimal media = 0 , soma = 7 , cont = 2;
media = soma / cont; //retorna 3.5
```

Segue outra forma mais simples e fácil:

```
double soma = 7;
double cont = 2;
var media = soma / cont; //retorna 3.5
```

Ou você pode usar `Convert.ToDouble()` ou `Convert.ToDecimal()`.

```
Double media = 0;
int soma = 7;
int cont = 2;
media = Convert.ToDouble(soma) / cont; // retorna 3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            double soma = 7;
            double cont = 2;
            double media = soma / cont;
            WriteLine(media);
        }
    }
```